# LINQ Split list into lists by date

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have list of objects `List<Payment>`. I would like to get list of lists grouped by `PaymentDate`. Something like that: `List<List<Payments>>` where each list of the list have same date (without hours).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`DateTime` has a [`Date` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
List<List<Payments>> result = payments 
    .GroupBy(p => p.PaymentDate.Date)
    .Select(g => g.ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Comment: LINQ is awkward! Calling .ToList() twice?

Comment: @codingbiz: Yes, one list for every group.

Comment: @codingbiz: When you want a list of lists, that makes perfect sense.

Comment: Helped me after 8 years!! Thank you..

Answer (score 7):

You can either use `GroupBy` as suggested by others, or you can just create a `Lookup`:

```
var lookup = payments.ToLookup(payment => payment.PaymentDate.Date);
```

You can iterate over that (using each group's key as the date) or fetch all the payments for a given date using the indexer. I usually find that a lookup is cleaner than using a nested collection such as a `List<List<...>>` or a `Dictionary<..., List<...>>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`GroupBy()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.groupby%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). The result will be of type `List<List<Payment>>`.

```
var result = payments.GroupBy(payment => payment.PaymentDate.Date)
                     .Select(group => group.ToList())
                     .ToList()
```